# PayPalのAPI情報（APIユーザー名、APIパスワード、API署名）の取得方法

Tags: paypal

PayPalのAPI情報（APIユーザー名、APIパスワード、API署名）の取得方法を教えてください

Comment: http://qiita.com/PayPal_MTS/items/2464e24676d275d6d72b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPalのAPI情報の取得方法は下記です：
www.paypal.comでログインして、「個人設定>販売ツール>API アクセス」で更新をクリックします。
または、下記URLにアクセスします：
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-api-access
表示されている「APIアクセス」画面で「API署名の表示」リンクをクリックしたら、API署名が表示されます。
もし「API署名の表示」リンクがなければ、「API証明書の請求」があると思いますので、「API証明書の請求」リンクをクリックして、
次の画面で左の「API署名を請求してください。」のチェックボックスをクリックして、「同意して送信」をクリックしてください、
API署名は次の画面で表示されると思います。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask